# Google maps api secrete key issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps

**I want to add api key as well as signature in my google maps api**.

After generating api key and secret key from google console, do we need to do anything like encryption or something or we can use direct that key in our url?

```
 $url .= "&key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz&signature=abcdefghijkliimnopqrstuvwxyz";
```

If I use signature then it's not loading my map, what's solution?

Comment: Yes you can directly use the api key in your URL without any modification.

Comment: its not loadnig map if i use signature ,

Comment: Google requies only api key with google maps JS . Can you please let us know why you are adding this with your URL

Comment: If i use only api key then some times my website not loads google static maps, so i want to try it with signature

Comment: THIS IS FOR STATIC MAP API.

Comment: I dont think that will be an issue at all, Its google policy that it will allow you some free number of request, if you exceed those limit it will turn off the map load any product your using like auto suggestion, maps etc etc

Comment: ok.But in case if i want to use signature then wats the suggestion

Comment: i this case you can remove the api key from the URL, and add client ID with this

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/image/auth I guess this will help you out

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/image/auth#digital-signature-premium

--Whats poinit number 3, pivate key and all

Comment: Just read the official documentation about api key and signatures in Static Maps https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/get-api-key#detailed-guides-to-generating-a-digital-signature. There are also code samples that show how to calculate your signature.

Comment: I tried to read the documentation, but documentation says you have to sign the URL, and we are creating the url manually in code, so how to do sign, using which alogo, what requirements all that kind of stuff i dnt kw, 

I can not find any videos or exact guide for how to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url='http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?&size=$dimensions&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&key=abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'; 
$url1=$url;
$url = parse_url($url1);

$urlPartToSign = $url['path'] . "?" . $url['query'];

// Decode the private key into its binary format
$decodedKey = decodeBase64UrlSafe('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxy');

// Create a signature using the private key and the URL-encoded
// string using HMAC SHA1. This signature will be binary.
$signature = hash_hmac("sha1",$urlPartToSign, $decodedKey,  true);

$encodedSignature = encodeBase64UrlSafe($signature);

$url=$url1."&signature=".$encodedSignature;

return saveImageUrlToDisk($imagePath, $url);

 }

function encodeBase64UrlSafe($value)
{
return str_replace(array('+', '/'), array('-', '_'),
    base64_encode($value));
}

// Decode a string from URL-safe base64
function decodeBase64UrlSafe($value)
{
return base64_decode(str_replace(array('-', '_'), array('+', '/'),
    $value));
}
```